# How to evenly add borders around table?

Tags: css, sapui5

I am currently trying to add borders around a table with an even thickness and amount. Here's a link to a JSbin that I have so far: https://jsbin.com/jibevalope/edit?html,css,js,output.

Right now the CSS looks like this:

```
.withGrid .sapMListTblCell:not(:first-child) {
 border: 1px solid;
}
```

I'm adding a border to every single table cell minus the first-child. This kind of works except the bottom of the bottom cells remain borderless and the top of the top cells have a border with a smaller thickness than the other borders.

How do I make this even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to give the whole table `border-right` and `border-bottom`, while giving all the cells the opposite, `border-left` and `border-top`.

```css
table {
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

td,
th {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kai</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```